# Filter for-each by XML attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

If I have the following XML:

```
<Results>
  <Option isDefault="true" value="1">
     <DisplayName>
        One
     </DisplayName>
  </Option>
  <Option value="2">
     <DisplayName>
        Two
     </DisplayName>
  </Option>
  <Option value="3">
     <DisplayName>
        Three
     </DisplayName>
  </Option>
</Results>
```

How can I access the `value` of the `Option` which has `isDefault="true"`?

So far I have tried:

```
<xsl:variable name="varName">
   <xsl:for-each select="Results/Option[isDefault='true']">
      <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know there is only a single such element or if you are interested only in the first such element you can simply use

```
<xsl:value-of select="Results/Option[@isDefault = 'true']/@value"/>
```

there is no need for a `for-each`. That applies to XSLT 1.0 and `value-of`, with 2.0 the above would output the `value` attribute values of all `Results/Option[@isDefault = 'true']` elements.

Answer (score 3):

If there is guaranteed to be at most one `Option` element whose `isDefault` attribute has the string value of `"true"`,

**then use this Xpath one-liner**:

```
/*/*[@isDefault='true']/@value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="varName">
   <xsl:for-each select="Results/Option[@isDefault='true']">
      <xsl:value-of select="@value" />
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```